# #if canImport(CoreImage) not working in swift package manager

Tags: swift, ciimage, swift-package-manager

I making library that uses CoreImage. Library supports Cocoapods, Carthage and Swift package manager.

When i build it in Swift Package Manager i got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EIP67Code.swift.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EIP67Code.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

When i use `#if canImport(CoreImage)`

```
#if canImport(CoreImage)
import CoreImage
extension Web3 {
  public struct EIP67CodeGenerator {
    public static func createImage(from: EIP67Code, scale: Double = 1.0) -> CIImage {
      guard let string = from.toString().addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return CIImage() }
      guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return CIImage() }
      let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator", parameters: ["inputMessage" : data, "inputCorrectionLevel":"L"])
      guard var image = filter?.outputImage else { return CIImage() }
      let transformation = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(scale), y: CGFloat(scale))
      image = image.transformed(by: transformation)
      return image
    }
  }
}
extension Web3.EIP67Code {
  public func toImage(scale: Double = 1.0) -> CIImage {
    return Web3.EIP67CodeGenerator.createImage(from: self, scale: scale)
  }
}
#endif
```

It works fine if i use `#if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)`

But CoreImage works on macOS so i still need this code at least for carthage/cocoapods

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just removed this file in Package.swift

.target(
name: "web3swift",
exclude: ["ObjectiveC", "Utils/EIP67Code.swift", "Migration-iOS.swift"]
),

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any solution so i just excluded this file in Package.swift

```
.target(
name: "web3swift",
dependencies: ["BigInt", "secp256k1", "keccak", "scrypt", "PromiseKit", "base58"],
exclude: ["ObjectiveC", "Utils/EIP67Code.swift", "Migration-iOS.swift"]
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some function in your framework which depended CoreImage not support the macOS 10.10 which is the default `Package.swift`. Try upgrading Package support start with macOS 10.12.

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    platforms: [
      .macOS(.v10_12),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker bug that manifests for frameworks that have moved or changed names. For the specific case of CoreImage, you can resolve the problem by either setting the deployment target to macOS 10.12 or importing QuartzCore instead of CoreImage.

If you open the framework's tbd file (`$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage.tbd`) and find symbols that start with `$ld$install_name$os`, then this framework is affected by this bug and you either need to use a deployment target that is more recent than the latest install_name in the list (in this case, more recent than 10.11) or you need to import the framework with its old name (in this name, QuartzCore).